# The code below is supposed to get the average from several dropdowns and print a message

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JavaScript. I am trying to get the average and write it to a paragraph tag. The values are being gotten from several dropdown menus with their ids. But it is not working. I appreciate any help. One of the dropdowns is below.

```
<label>IT5413 Software Design and Development</label>
<select name="IT5413" id="grade1">
<option value="4">A</option>
<option value="3">B</option>
<option value="2">C</option>
<option value="1">D</option>
<option value="0">F</option>
</select>

function submitGrade() {
var a = document.getElementById("grade1");
var score1 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
var b = document.getElementById("grade2");
var score2 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
var c = document.getElementById("grade3");
var score3 = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
var d = document.getElementById("grade4");
var score4 = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
   
var GPA=(score1 + score2 + score3 + score4)/4
       
if (GPA > 3.7) {
document.getElementById("conclusion").innerHTML = "Your GPA is " + GPA + ". Congratulations! You 
are eligible to apply for the student assistant position. Please follow this link"; <a href='#' 
target='_blank'>CARIT application</a>;}
else if (GPA <= 3.7) {
document.getElementById("conclusion").innerHTML = "Your GPA is " + GPA + ". Unfortunately, your 
GPA is below the required level to apply for the student assistant position.";}
else if (GPA > 3.2) {
document.getElementById("conclusion").innerHTML = "Your GPA is " + GPA + ". Congratulations! You 
are eligible to apply for the student assistant position. Please follow this link"; <a href='#' 
target='_blank'>CARIT application</a>;}
else if (GPA <= 3.2) {
document.getElementById("conclusion").innerHTML = "Your GPA is " + GPA + ". Unfortunately, your 
GPA is below the required level to apply for the student assistant position.";}
```

Comment: values are strings.  use `Number(......value)`  Also, why not use array?

Comment: Your first two `if` conditions cover all possible numeric values, so the last two conditions can never be reached.

Comment: you can give all the `select`s a dummy class, say "classGrade", then get all of them (0, 4 as in your example, any) by using `document.getElementsByClassName("classGrade")` and iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

The selected values are of type `string`, convert it to a `number` first, prior to any arithmetic operation

```
var a = document.getElementById("grade1");
var score1 = Number(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
var b = document.getElementById("grade2");
var score2 = Number(b.options[b.selectedIndex].value);
var c = document.getElementById("grade3");
var score3 = Number(c.options[c.selectedIndex].value);
var d = document.getElementById("grade4");
var score4 = Number(d.options[d.selectedIndex].value);
var GPA=(score1 + score2 + score3 + score4)/4
```

Answer (score 0):

They way you have the "if" statements ordered, any value <= 3.7 will fall true.

If the GPA = "3.6999" then the second if statement falls true.

If the GPA = "1.1" then the second if statement falls true.

Comment: I changed those strings to numbers, but it did not print anything.

Comment: I converted those strings to numbers by using parseFloat as following, but it did not work.             var GPA=(parseFloat(score1) + parseFloat(score2) + parseFloat(score3) + parseFloat(score4))/4